# Ubuntu 12.04 Server auto mount usb to static location

Tags: usb, automount

I am trying to get a USB external hard drive (ext4) to automatically mount when it is plugged in. I used to have it working but has since stopped. I have tried the usbmount package however it will mount it at /media/usb# and the number can change depending on the order in which it is plugged in to.

The drive has a label so is it possible to auto mount the drive to /media/drivelabel

Also when unmounted the directory should not exist as a program automatically backs up to the drive when it is seen, if the directory is there it backs up to the local disk.

Thanks
Harv

Comment: Just a quick hint: look up `udev automatically mount` on Google.